# Is it possible to do a common plot in parallel (with foreach)?

Tags: r, data-visualization, parallel-processing

The problem in short: I have to visualise an optimisation process on a plot. On a pre-plotted device the new solutions (as points(x,y)) should appear as they are available. I have working sequential code by a nested loop, but it should possible to make it parallel. I gave a try with the foreach package (with the doParallel backend) but the spawned processes can not plot on the parent processe's device - obviously.
Is it possible to overcome this maybe with another package or anyhow?

Comment: I would imagine that if you create an empty plot, you might be able to pass the device around to each of the spawned Rscript sessions.

Comment: Do you have any suggestiont how to pass the device around among sessions? I couldn't find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have one process plot to another process's graphics device in R.  Instead, the processes need to send messages to a designated process that does all of the graphics operations.  That would be rather difficult using parallel or foreach/doParallel, but it's relatively easy using foreach with a parallel backend that supports processing worker results on-the-fly, such as doMPI or doRedis.  In that case, you can plot the points in the combine function as they are computed by the workers.  Here's a simple example:

```
library(doMPI)
nworkers <- 4
cl <- startMPIcluster(nworkers)
comm <- cl$comm  # get communicator number
registerDoMPI(cl)
cap <- capabilities()
if (cap['aqua']) quartz() else if (cap['X11']) X11() else windows()
plot(integer(0), integer(0),
     main='Random points generated by doMPI workers',
     xlab='X', ylab='Y', xlim=c(1,100), ylim=c(1,100))
legend('topright', sprintf('worker %d', 1:nworkers), pch=1:nworkers)

# The argument "p" is a list of arguments to the function "points"
plotpoint <- function(x, p) {
  do.call('points', p)
  x
}

foreach(i=icount(100), .combine='plotpoint',
        .init=NULL, .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
  Sys.sleep(abs(rnorm(1, mean=3)))
  list(x=sample(100,1), y=sample(80,1), pch=mpi.comm.rank(comm))
}
text(50, 90, 'Finished')
Sys.sleep(10)

closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

I'm throwing away the results since they are only used to call `points`, but you could modify `plotpoint` to save some part of the result in the first argument `x`.  Just make sure that you modify the `.init` argument to the appropriate data structure.

Comment: I think this is what I wanted, but I'm on Windos and no binary for doMPI, maybe with doRedis. Anyway thank you, regards, Peter

Comment: registerDoRedis hangs :-(

Comment: Did you start a redis server?

Comment: No, but finally I had time to experimenting and worked with redis server. Thank you again, this solves my problem. (Actually, it would be preferable without any supplemental process - because my strickty limited working environment...)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this:

```
foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% with(env.profile(.GlobalEnv), #Your Code#)
```

I'm not sure if this would work or not. You may be running into problems because of the sequential nature of plotting with base R graphics works. You might also try creating a list and just adding the results of each iteration to the list during the %dopar% call. After it's finished, you should be able to just use lapply(point.list, points).

Comment: I'll try it. Does %dopar% pass its environment to rscript processes?

Comment: I'm not sure. It probably does, but I assumed that you were already using %dopar%. I just searched for the foreach package that you mentioned, and there was no function called doParallel, only %dopar% which seemed to fit what you were talking about. If it does pass it, you can do it without the env.profile call and just run your code afterward.